# How do I change <tr> bgcolor with Javascript using a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-color

I have this html

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            Hello
        </td>
        <td>
            my friend!
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            ...
        </td>
        <td>
            ...
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

What do I need to do if I want to change my `<tr>` bgcolor when the checkbox is activated? I guess I will need to do something with `onclick()` maybe.

EDIT: What I need is that the checkbox should modify only his current row.

Comment: if you move the checkbox outside the table you can also do it in pure css: http://jsbin.com/egihej/1/edit

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I guess that one checkbox won't be the only one in the final table.

Comment: I actually need it inside the table, and I want only the "current" selected row to be modified.

Comment: @abierto Are you open to use a library? e.g. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)?

Comment: Not really, because in this project I'm using JSP and Javascript. I'm actually not in the "mood" to use jQuery only for this trick... But if is necessary I will use it.

Comment: It's absolutely not necessary...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possible approaches:

```
document.getElementById('table').onclick = function(e) {
    var e = e || event,
        el = e.srcElement || e.target;
    if (el.tagName == 'INPUT') {
        el.parentNode.parentNode.className = el.checked ? 'active' : '';
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TQbpH/2/

In this example event bubbles to the parent table which listens to it, and then it's dispatched if needed.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/L6xsB/

```
$(function () {
    $('tr').on('click', 'input:checkbox', function () {
        $(this).parents('tr').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
tr.active {
    background-color: #FFC;
}
```

Comment: I'd be careful suggestion jQuery if the OP did not include it in the question or question-tags. (downvote wasn't me)